# How to Model one to many relationship with Dapper AND ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to Dapper or even ASP.NET MVC and I'm trying to write what should be a very simple CRUD app. Basically I have two tables User and File. User table stores some details about the User and when you click details it should display some more details and any files that user will upload (there can be none or up to 10).

File table stores the filenames. How do I create a model and then view for something like this using Dapper. It seems simple but I can't seem to figure this out. Can I put both models on my view and then loop through the file model to display the files if any. if so then how?

here is my details controller.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        Users user = new Users();
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            user= db.Query<Users>("SELECT * FROM Users As t LEFT JOIN Files AS f ON  t.EID = f.EID WHERE t.EID=" +id, new{ id }).SingleOrDefault() ;
        }
        return View(trade);
    }
```

Comment: What the purpose of the details view? Display files for the user or you want some additional user info there as well?

Comment: Display files and some additional info since it's probably not possible to display it all in a grid like format on index page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try to read more about architecture, learn how to organize your code at the first place. For instance calling database directly from controller is a bad idea. I would do something like this:

Move all database calls to separate repository classes according to responsibilities.

```
public class UsersRepository
{
    public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        User user = new User();
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            user= db.Query<User>("SELECT * FROM Users where EID=@id", new{ id }).SingleOrDefault();
        }
        return user;
    }

    public List<File> GetUserFiles(int id)
    {
        List<File> files = new List<File>();
        using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            files = db.Query<File>("SELECT * FROM Files where UserID=@id", new{ id });
        }
        return files;
    }
}
```

Create model to store your data for detail view

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Create service or engine to organize you business logic

```
public class UsersService
{   
    private UsersRepository _usersRepository;

    public UsersService()
    {
        _usersRepository = new UsersRepository();
    }

    public UserDetails GetUserDetails(int userId)
    {
        var details = new UserDetails();
        details.User = _usersRepository.GetUser(id);
        details.Files = _usersRepository.GetUserFiles(id);
        return details;     
    }       
}
```

Call it in controller

```
public class UsersController : Controller // or whatever the base class you have
{       
    private UsersService _usersService;

    public UsersController()
    {
        _usersService = new UsersService();
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var details = _usersService.GetUserDetails(id);
        return View(details);
    }   
}
```

But keep in mind that its very simplified example. For instance it is better to use dependency injection rather than initialize services or repositories in constructor. Also in many cases it is not very smart to use same classes for view and repository logic, consider using DTO and domain classes insead. For simple apps and demonstraion it should be ok though.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's beginning to make sense but you're right I need to read a book about MVC architecture.